# Python requests unable to access https site

Tags: python-2.7, https, web-scraping, python-requests

I run this code:

```
import requests

loginurl = 'https://auth.cbssports.com/login/index'

try:
    response = requests.get(loginurl)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print "Login URL is BAD"

response = requests.get(loginurl)
```

It consistently returns this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='auth.cbssports.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/index (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

I am able to access this url manually. I can't figure out why Python can't. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible I need to use OpenSSL? I have this but I don't know how to add it to the requests.get command to make it decode the https.