# python requests.get using auth=(user, pass) not working

Tags: python, python-requests

when I send the credentials as part of the URL I get a proper response:

```
requests.get('<URL>?user=admin+pass=admin', params={"cmd": "getpower"})

response.code = 200
response.text ==> P61=0,P62=0,P63=1,P64=0,P65=1,P66=1,P67=1,P68=1
```

but when trying to do so using auth=(user, pass), it is not working:

```
requests.get('<URL>', params={"cmd": "getpower"}, auth=("admin", "admin"))

response.code = 200
response.text ==> HTML page - that actually present cookie timeout
```

Comment: Use `requests.post(...` instead.

Comment: cannot use requests.post() - it causes an exception...

Comment: Are you sure that the server side is expecting user and password passed as Basic authentication ?

Comment: Guillaume - I am not sure about authentication type, but when I tried to use HTTPDigestAuth or  HTTPProxyAuth, I got None response. If I send all parameters as part of URL, including User+Pass, it is working fine, so I guess it uses the default basic authentication.

Comment: stovfl - question was edited. Also when using requests.post(), I get the following:  {ConnectionError}('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Answer (score 1):

> **Comment**: the order of parameters in URL is critical

There is another Difference, `param` are `encoded`, so `=` becomes `%3D`:

```
# '<URL>?user=admin+pass=admin'
url:http://httpbin.org/anything?user=admin+pass=admin&cmd=getpower

# requests.get(url, params=params
url:http://httpbin.org/anything?user=admin+pass%3Dadmin&cmd=getpower

# `dict` is **not** Ordered, it's possible to become reversed
url:http://httpbin.org/anything?cmd=getpower&user=admin+pass%3Dadmin
```

To overcome this, use:

```
auth = {'user':'admin+pass=admin'}
params = {"cmd": "getpower"}
params.update(auth)
params_str = "&".join("%s=%s" % (k,v) for k,v in params.items())
r = requests.get(url, params=params_str)
```

**Conclusion: I see no way to overcome passing as Part of the URL.**
Assuming broken Server?
Read this Relevant SO [post-request-failing-errno-10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487818/python-post-request-failing-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-c)

---

> **Comment**;: ...  trying to add User+Pass to params, did not work

I overlooked that you are using **Plus** instead of **&**, so `auth` has to be:

```
auth = {'user': 'admin pass=admin'}
```

Try also:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=params, auth=('admin pass=admin', ''))
```

---

> **Question**: requests.get using auth=(user, pass) not working

Seems that the Server doesn't support `post` and `auth=`.

To send as Part of the URL:

> **Note**: Using `get` and as Part of the URL is unsecure.

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/anything'
auth = {'user': 'admin pass=admin'}
params = {"cmd": "getpower"}
params.update(auth)
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I understand the security issue of passing this data as part of the URL, but its currently seems to be the only working way... Also while trying to add User+Pass to params, did not work - I got response code 401.

Comment: Still no good. I noticed of 2 issues: 1. the order of parameters in URL is critical, if I change it it doesn't work. 2. In URL I use (+) to add parameters, while when using params, it uses (&), which is again no good.